# Buddypress Multi user roles

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have a website built in WordPress 3.3.1. My site have two types of roles lets say jobseeker and employers. Now I have installed buddypress social networking plugin and activated the registration process. Now I need two separate link for jobseeker and employers through which users can get registered as per their roles in buddypress and as well as in wordpress.

Many Thanks To Anyone That Helps,

Answer (score 2):

Buddypress User Account type just updated.. which allows to assign different role to different account type

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing out there that will do exactly what you're looking for, however there is a new plugin that may get you going in the right direction.  It's called Buddypress User Account Types and can be found at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-user-account-type-lite/installation/